# Angularjs $state error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem implementing states to my angularjs application. I have seen many had the same problem but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

My **app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource','testCtrl']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider,$httpProvider) {


        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $stateProvider

 .state('app.registerPage', {
                    url: "/tp/AddQ",
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: "views/Registration_view.php",
                            controller: 'testCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                });

        $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/AEAS/admin/');
    }]);
```

**my controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$state', function ($scope, $http,$state) {


        $scope.click = function(){

           console.log("done");
           $state.go('app.registerPage');


        };

    }]);
```

**my view**

```
<body>

<div class="container" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-app="app">
            <div class="row">
                <form role="form" ng-submit="submit(data)">

                    <h1>Welcome to Heart attack predictor!</h1>

    <div id="body">

            <button><a href=""  ng-click="click();">Edit</a></button>

    </div>
                </form>

</div>
</div>

</body>


<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/Controllers/testCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

This is the error I get

```
   Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=t...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:40:60
    at q (http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:39:135)
    at http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:39:304
    at q (http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:39:135)
    at eb (http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:43:164)
    at c (http://localhost/Heart_Attack_Predictor/angularjs/angular.min.js:20:463
```

Comment: try changing the controller to var app = angular.module('app') , normally [] creates a new app

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, include `app.js` before `testCtrl.js`.

Then, in `testCtrl.js`, you are re-declaring the variable `app` which is defined in `app.js`. So, change to:

```
app.controller('testCtrl');
```

instead of

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl')
```

Comment: it's not seems to be working. can you tell me what angular files I should load to get $states working. I added angular-ui-router but not working for me.

Comment: It shouldn't throw the error atleast imo. Don't know whats going wrong. Can you create a plunker?

Comment: i'm doing this in a codeigniter framework.. can that be a issue?